# Issue running Tkinter GUI from VBA

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, tkinter

I have an access database that is paired with a GUI based python web scraper for data collection. I am trying to write VBA to kick off that python process, but all I get is a blip of the command line and the GUI doesn't appear.

````
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """My path to python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "Path to GUI main.py"
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    
End Sub```
````

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space between executable and Python script path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VBA code works fine in my PC.  I could run "hello_world.py" from your VBA code. Check your Python code, if it can run from command line.

Open cmd window,

```
cd Path to GUI main.py
python main.py


# Python tkinter hello world program 
from tkinter import *
root = Tk() 
a = Label(root, text ="Hello World") 
a.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to run it from command line, just needed to manage my environment and dependencies.